# Firebase: how to query non-overlapping data from two nodes?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

This is how the data looks like:

datastructure

```
"uid0" : {
        "name": "adam"
},
"uid1" : {
        "name": "jonh",
        "likes" : {
          "uid2" : true
        }
},
"uid2" : {
        "name": "jane",
        "likes" : {
          "uid0" : true,
          "uid1" : true
        }
},
"uid3" : {
        "name": "mark"
}
```

How to find all users who have not been liked by uid2? (i.e result should be uid3, in the case above)

codepen: http://codepen.io/rattanakchea/pen/gPwpQq?editors=101

firebase: https://datastructure.firebaseio.com/users.json

Comment: Can you edit your post and copy/paste the actual (edited) data structure instead of a graphic?

Comment: Ah - much clearer question. See my really-long-winded updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a slightly different structure would provide more flexibility

```
     users
       -Ji94-0df-k00ksdf
         name: "john"
         liked: true
       -kKoakoksdookasdp
         name: "jane"
         liked: true
       -Lkaamsioadoisjg
         name: "james"
         liked: false
```

query the users node where liked = false

You can expand on this by adding say.. a number_of_likes as well

```
        users
               -Ji94-0df-k00ksdf
                 name: "john"
                 number_of_likes: 1,000,000
               -Lkaamsioadoisjg
                 name: "james"
                 number_of_likes: 0
```

The you could query for anyone that is not liked (0) or the most liked (1M) or anything in between

**EDIT**: update and add another answer(s) based on updated information

There are a few simple solutions:

One is to track likes and no_status within each user. With this structure is trivial to find which users uid_2 has not likes or dislikes

```
user
  uid_0
    likes
     uid_1
     uid_2
    no_status
     uid_3
  uid_1
    likes
     uid_0
     uid_2
    no_status
     uid_3
  uid_2
    likes
     uid_0
     uid_1
    no_status
     uid_3
```

Another option along the same lines is to dump the boolean and go with a tri-state (or however many states are needed)

```
user
  uid_0
    likable_status
     uid_1: "yes"
     uid_2: "no"
     uid_3: "unknown"
  uid_1
    likable_status
     uid_0: "yes"
     uid_2: "yes"
     uid_3: "unknown"
  uid_2
    likable_status
     uid_0: "yes"
     uid_1: "unknown"
     uid_3: "yes"
```

With this if you want to know which users uid_2 has not decided on, query for unknown.

Finally - you *can* test to see if a node exists. So you could read a node to see if it's exists: something like

```
ref = "/user/uid_2/liked/uid_3"
```

and if it doesn't exist then... uid_2 has not liked uid_3.

here's some obj c code (from the firebase site)

```
[ref observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.value == [NSNull null]) {
    // The value is null
  }
}];
```

While this tests a single node, it would again be trivial to build a list of uid's and test each ref within a path to see if it exists.

Note:
*Disk space is cheap* so don't worry about data duplication; it's standard practice in NoSQL databases and part of what makes them screaming fast.

**Updated edit with real-world data**

structure (note that in each uid_x; liked is who they liked and not_liked is who they don't):

```
users
  uid_0
   liked
      uid_1: "yes"
   not_liked
      uid_2: "no"
      uid_3: "no"
 uid_1
   liked
      uid_0: "yes"
      uid_2: "yes"
   not_liked
      uid_3: "no"
 uid_2
   liked
      uid_0: "yes"
      uid_3: "yes"
   not_liked  
      uid_1: "no"
 uid_3
   liked
      uid_1: "yes"
   not_liked
      uid_0: "no"
      uid_2: "no"
```

And the code:

```
Firebase *ref = [self.myRootRef childByAppendingPath:@"users"];

Firebase *userNotLikedRef = [ref childByAppendingPath:@"uid_2/not_liked"];

[userNotLikedRef observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

   NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value);

}];
```

this results in all of the uid_2's that are not liked (uid_1 in this case)

One more quick example using a flatter structure and a query (note that the children in each uid_x node is the uid of who liked them)

```
users
  uid_0
    uid_2: "yes"
    uid_3: "yes"
  uid_1
    uid_0: "yes"
    uid_2: "yes"
  uid_2
    uid_1: "yes"
    uid_3: "yes"
  uid_3
    uid_0: "yes"
    uid_1: "yes"
```

and the query

```
Firebase *ref = [self.myRootRef childByAppendingPath:@"users"];

FQuery *q1 = [ref queryOrderedByChild:@"uid_2"];
FQuery *q2 = [q1 queryEqualToValue:@"yes"];

[q2 observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

    NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value);

}];
```

This results in the uid's that uid_2 liked (which are uid_0 and uid_1)

Comment: I updated the data and question to make it more clear. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm confused by this, this entire structure would have to be a child of a user, and every user would have one of these collections as a child, right? The `liked` value being a boolean means it's a one-to-one mapping. Liked by whom?

Comment: @Jay, with tri-state structure. For example, how to query all users whom uid_0 have not liked, in other words status is "no"? Do we still need to loop all children nodes of uid_0->likable_status, and compare each user_id value?

Comment: There's a little ambiguity here as there are three possibilities (based on the question). They have been liked (YES) they have been not liked (NO) and they have neither been liked or not liked (unknown). I don't know if those three fall within the parameters of your project.  But, to answer the question, create a query on the user path where uid_0 is YES (returns uid_1 and uid_2 in my example). Or query for UID_2 is NO, which returns uid_0 in my example.

Comment: Your query is: find whom have like uid_0. But I'm more interested in: finding whom uid_0 have liked. There is subtle difference. I made a codepen, but it does not work: http://codepen.io/rattanakchea/pen/gPwpQq?editors=101. Could you give it a try?

Comment: So the original question is to find the users that have not been liked by uid2. The setup mentioned will do that. Within uid2/likeable_status is a list of the other uid's. Those that are false are not liked by uid2. Even the first setup I mentioned can do it; i called the node no_status but it could be called not_liked and keep the not_liked uid's within that node. In that case, reading in the data at  /users/uid_2/not_liked will result in the users uid_2 doesn't like.

Comment: I updated my super-lengthy-wall-of-text answer with data structures and code examples that are tested and provide the results you are after.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it answered my original questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase's querying abilities are pretty minimal, and there's simply no way to get the information you want in a query with your present data structure.

You have three options:

1. Suck down the entire users collection and figure it out in javascript. Depending on the size of the collection, this could be viable. Just create an array of userIds, and splice out any that are in the user's liked list. However, at scale this is probably too much data to pull down at once.
2. Create and maintain a collection for this purpose, a `notliked` collection that is updated every time a new user joins, or a user likes another. This seems unwieldy.
3. Do the query elsewhere, in a "real" database. Firebase is great for a lot of things, however using it as a primary datastore if you need complex querying is tough. I've found it's most useful as a front for calculated data from another more robust database. It's strength is in its scaling and live update abilities.

Comment: I currently do the Step 1. There is unnecessary checking for liked users in each query. Scaling might be an issue down the road. In Step 2, each user would carry a notLiked collection, which would create a lot repeated data.

Comment: Do you have a server for this, or is the client interfacing purely with firebase for all actions?

Comment: No server at the moment. Would a change in data structure help?

Comment: You'd have to maintain a collection specifically for this, as per my #2 suggestion, as you can't query on the absence of data with Firebase. Then on every user added, you'd have to update all children in that collection, and is probably not a scalable solution either. I don't see a solution for this that doesn't involve making a backend for your app.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how to integrate both backend and firebase. Is there a good place where I can start looking at?

Comment: @DylanWatt I updated my answer but to clarify; you can definitely check for the the absence of data within Firebase. If a  node doesn't exist then a query or added/value event returns null.

Comment: That's not what I mean by querying on the absence. I mean the only only query that firebase has is `orderByChild` where you can use `equalTo` and `start` and `end` on that order. You can't do `notEqualTo` or `notSet`. You can get children based on values that exist, but not on values that don't exist.

Comment: @DylanWatt Yes - I understand your point. However, you can in fact get query results for values that don't exist. The last code example in my answer, change this statement [q1 queryEqualToValue:@"yes"];   to this   [q1 queryEqualToValue:nil];.   The original 'yes' version return uid_0 and uid_1 because they both have uid_2 = yes. However, changing it to nil returns uid_2 and uid_3 because neither of those have a uid_2 (a value that does not exist)